# How to get actual date value from hidden date input field of (mdbootstrap) "pickadate" using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In  mdbootstrap `datepicker1` , need formatted `(yyyy-mm-dd / yyyy/mm/dd)` not string formated date like '1 December, 2020'. how to get it from the hidden input field using jquery?

```
<div class="md-form ">
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="cp_date" name="cp_date" class="form-control datepicker" data-value="<?php echo '['.date('Y,M,d').']' ; ?>" autofocus="" onchange="getdate()" >
      <label for="cp_date" class="font-weight-bold">Crawled Date: </label>
</div>
```

and the function is:

```
function getdate() {
var c_date = $('cp_date').val(); alert(c_date);}
```

calling pickadate with

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate();
```

it is getting like "1 December, 2020". but I need like "2020/12/01".

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are you using *datepicker* plugin?

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant framework and plugin.

Comment: So you need to define **dateFormat** like *$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ "dateFormat":"yy-mm-dd" });*

Comment: I'm using pickadate.js not datepicker

Comment: or can say picker-date.js. which a have found from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/forms/date-picker1/

Answer (score 0):

You can change date format in *jQueryUI Datepicker plugin* like **yyyy-mm-dd** or **yyyy/mm/dd** with options method by **dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'** or **dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd'**.

Source: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats

```js
$(function() {
    $('.datepicker1').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      onSelect: function(dt){
        alert(dt)
      }
    });
    $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
      onSelect: function(dt){
        alert(dt)
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  Date <small>(YYYY-MM-DD)</small> :<br>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker1" size="30" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  Date <small>(YYYY/MM/DD)</small>:<br>
  <input type="text" class="datepicker2" size="30" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD">
</div>
```

Comment: here I'm using pickadate.js not jquery datepicker.

Comment: I'm working with https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/forms/date-picker1/

Comment: You can try something like this.
*$('.datepicker').pickadate({
format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
});*

You can refer to this **link** https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/forms/date-picker1/#formats

Comment: You can try here also on live https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/2835048?action=prism_export#js-tab-view

Comment: tank you, Raeesh Alam. ` hiddenPrefix: 'prefix__',
hiddenSuffix: '__suffix' ` also a way to solve. I've found it from your ref link.

Comment: Welcome! If you want to get selected date so don't need to use onchange() event. There is predefined method **onSet** in **pickadate** library. So use like this **$('.datepicker').pickadate({
format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
  onSet: function(context) {
  var d = new Date(context.select);
    var ts = new Date(d);
    alert(ts.getFullYear() + '/' + (ts.getMonth()+1) + '/' + ts.getDate());
 }
})**

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've found the right solution for this. what I have done is like....

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',hiddenName: true});
```

this is the first calling for `.datepicker` class. then changes made in function `getdate()`

```
function getdate() {var c_date = $("input[name=cp_date]").val(); alert(c_date);}
```

this `hiddenName: true` works like it removes name attribute from date input field and add it to hidden input field. then it's easy to get value using `$("input[name=cp_date]").val();`.